# How can I augment a directive's link function with angular's decorator pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm working on an Angular library and looking for a way to extend a directive using the decorator pattern:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).decorator('originaldirectiveDirective', [
  '$delegate', function($delegate) {

    var originalLinkFn;
    originalLinkFn = $delegate[0].link;

    return $delegate;
  }
]);
```

What would be the best way to augment the original directive using this pattern?
(Example usage: to have additional watches or extra event listeners on the directive without modifying it's code directly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify or extend directive's `controller` quite easily. If it's `link` you are looking for (as in your example), it's not that much harder. Just modify directive's `compile` function in `config` phase.

For example:

**HTML template**

```
<body>
  <my-directive></my-directive>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])

  .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('myDirectiveDirective', function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];

      directive.compile = function() {
        return function(scope) {
          directive.link.apply(this, arguments);
          scope.$watch('value', function() {
            console.log('value', scope.value);
          });
        };
      };

      return $delegate;
    });
  }) 

  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.value = 0; 
      },
      template: '<input type="number" ng-model="value">'
    };
  });
```

Now you have decorated `myDirective` to log `value` when ever it has changed.

Related plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/mDYxKj

Comment: Thanks for the instructive example Mikko. Is there a particular reason you do the decoration in `config` phase?

Comment: Before you had to do it in config, not any more, it seems.

Comment: @MikkoViitala Thank you. The `directive.compile` was very eye opener.